# How to upload file in sharepoint 2010 using javascript or CSOM?

Tags: 2010

How to upload file in sharepoint 2010 using javascript?

Please give me solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer below link:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-uploads-document-in-document-library-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013-o365

Answer (score 1):

Insert below code in a content editor web part. [Ref](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-2016-javascript-object-model/) that's it, you are done!

** below code will upload the file in site default document library, you can change the path in case you want.

```
<html>  
<head>  

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        varfileInput;  
        $(document).ready(function()  
        {  
            fileInput = $("#getFile");  
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);  
        });  

        function registerClick()  
        {  
            //Register File Upload Click Event  
            $("#addFileButton").click(readFile);  
        }  
        vararrayBuffer;  

        function readFile()  
        {  
            //Get File Input Control and read th file name  
            varelement = document.getElementById("getFile");  
            varfile = element.files[0];  
            varparts = element.value.split("\\");  
            varfileName = parts[parts.length - 1];  
            //Read File contents using file reader  
            varreader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e)  
            {  
                uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName);  
            }  
            reader.onerror = function(e)  
            {  
                alert(e.target.error);  
            }  
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);  
        }  
        varattachmentFiles;  

        function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName)  
        {  
            //Get Client Context,Web and List object.  
            varclientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
            varoWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
            varoList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');  
            //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
            varbytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
            vari, length, out = '';  
            for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1)  
            {  
                out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
            }  
            varbase64 = btoa(out);  
            //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
            varcreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
            createInfo.set_content(base64);  
            createInfo.set_url(fileName);  
            //Add the file to the library  
            varuploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)  
            //Load client context and execcute the batch  
            clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
        }  

        function QuerySuccess()  
        {  
            console.log('File Uploaded Successfully.');  
        }  

        function QueryFailure(sender, args)  
        {  
            console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());  
        }  
    </script>  
</head>  

<body>  
    <input id="getFile" type="file" /><br />  
    <input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" />  
</body>  
<html>
```